# How to check if y outputs are unique for the duplicates in x inputs?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples, unique

I have two numpy arrays. Shape of the first one (X input) is `(337, 3, 30)`, but the second (y output) is `(337, 8)`. In the first one there are many duplicates. How can I find amount of the uniques outputs for these duplicate? I mean checking, example, if in 10 duplicates there are 10 same values in second array (1 unique) or something different.

For example: X matrix has duplicates and I know it due to Counter function. Each X case corresponds to Y cell. Lets say two first rows of X matrix are the same, then I want to check if the first two rows in matrix Y are the same, or different. If they are different - how many of scenarios are there. I want to make such analysis.

Edit: Now I created a list. Each list element has a tuple in which on the first posistion is X element and on the second corresponding y element. Maybe that's the better way to solve the problem?

```py
list_of_tups[0]
```

gives such output:

```py
(array([[-0.63434589, -0.29900576,  1.58925953,  1.58925953, -1.25893308,
          0.76126064, -0.87056499,  0.31736156, -3.86900902, -1.        ,
         -0.23059131, -0.78751513,  0.510954  , -1.        , -0.30160512,
          1.        ,  5.8423382 ,  0.02629687,  0.02696755,  1.65819659,
          4.21574931, -1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [-1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ,
         -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ,
         -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ,
         -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ,
         -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ,
         -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ],
        [-1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ,
         -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ,
         -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ,
         -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ,
         -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ,
         -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        , -1.        ]]),
 array([ 0.     ,  0.14983,  0.     , -0.26847, -0.     , -0.26847,
        -0.     ,  0.14983]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem. As an example I took 100 random integers for each array.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(0, 100, (337, 3, 30))
y = np.random.randint(0, 100, (337, 8))


#uniques values in array x
def find_uniques(x):
    uniques = np.unique(x)
    return uniques
    
find_uniques(x)
```

Comment: I see I wrong explained it. X matrix has duplicates and I know it due to Counter function. Each X case corresponds to Y cell. Lets say two first rows of X matrix are the same, then I want to check if the first two rows in matrix Y are the same, or different. I want to make such analysis.